# Xamarin ITMS-90809 error Depcreciated Api Usage

Tags: ios, api, xamarin

First off, there are many of these topics here, and I have read a lot but could not find a solution, as it was only a warning, but now its a rejection.

I submitted my app and got this email:

```
Dear Developer,
We identified one or more issues with a recent 
delivery for your app, "Gallery-Share" 1.0 (1.0). 
Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct 
the following issues in your next delivery: 
ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - 
Apple will stop accepting submissions of new apps that use 
UIWebView APIs starting from April 2020. See 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information. 
After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to App Store Connect. 
Best regards,
The App Store Team
```

I'm not aware that I used any Webviews.. I made my app with xamarin so for me this message is a bit cryptic.. What is the cause and solution for this message? How can I figure out where I used Webview, and how can I replace it with something apple likes?

Comment: Xamarin has a blog post covering what to do: "UIWebView Deprecation and Xamarin.Forms:  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks, tried doing what is written there, but now i get a error about the thinning process.. Is that related to this, or do I have to make a new question?

Comment: What error is the linker process giving you? (And yes, it would be better to ask a new question)

Comment: @SushiHangover whats the linker process? where can I find this? posted the question here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61056855/xamarin-submitted-app-error-occurred-in-thinning-process ps: if you post your comment as answer i can accpet it..