# Xamarin - Submitted App - Error occurred in thinning process

Tags: ios, xamarin, app-store, app-thinning

I submitted an app to the Appstore but it gets refused with this message:

```
While processing your iOS app, Appname, errors occurred in the app thinning process, 
and your app couldn’t be thinned. If your app contains bitcode, bitcode processing 
may have failed. Because of these errors, this build of your app will not be 
able to be submitted for review or placed on the App Store. 
For information that may help resolve this issue, see Tech Note 2432.
```

I added this to my cproj file in the build iphone section:

```
<MtouchEnableBitcode>false</MtouchEnableBitcode>
```

I also folowed this to solve the UIWebView problem. no idea if it is related:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/

also updated all the packages to the latest, tried to put the minimum target OS to 9.0 tried to put enablebitcode to true, tried everything i was able to find online but without any result..

Nuget packages I use:

in the main project:

```
Newtonsoft.Json
RedCorner.Forms
SkiaSharp
sqlite-net-pcl
Xamarin.essentials
xamarin.ffimageloading
xamarin.ffimageloading.forms
xamarin.ffimageloading.svg
xamarin.ffimageloading.svg.forms
xamarin.ffimageloading.transformations
xamarin.forms
```

inside the IOS project:

```
sqlite-net-pcl
xamarin.essentials
xamarin.forms
```

These are all up to date... the app compiles and works great in the simulator..

Any idea on how I can sovle this frustrating problem?

UPDATE:

tried to package in Xamarin and then distribute in ad Hoc mode in xcode, and there it throws this error:

```
 Failed to read property list: $ cd 
/var/folders/pm/pwvftt8s1vbg4q6nj04blyym0000gn/T/
IDEDistributionOptionThinning.\~\~\~WPqMdz/Payload && /usr/bin/plutil -convert binary1 -o - -- GalShare.iOS.app/LaunchScreen.storyboardc/Info.plist
Status: pid 7230 exit 1
Stdout:
GalShare.iOS.app/LaunchScreen.storyboardc/Info.plist: Property List error: 
Cannot parse a NULL or zero-length data / JSON error: No value.

Stderr:
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that there was no valid image in the spashscreen.. adding an image fixed the problem

Comment: It seems that you have solved your issue now, please remember to mark your reply as answer, it may be helpful to other community members, thanks.